# Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager. Soft delete works but i can't register softdeleteable filter

Tags: doctrine, symfony5, doctrine-extensions

I'm having issues with soft delete from "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" package. I'm running Symfony 5.4.

SoftDelete functionality actually works fine, but I can't set up the softdeleteable filter.

This is my config/packages/doctrine.yaml file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

This is my config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml file:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            softdeleteable: true
```

And, this is part of my config/services.yaml file:

```
services:
    gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
```

When I try to delete some entity, it works fine, it updates deletedAt field. But, I want to add softdeleteable filter, and that's when the things stop working. I added gedmo.listener.softdeleteable service to services.yaml and filters part to doctrine.yaml, and i get this error:

```
Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager!
```

I can't figure out where I'm making a mistake, and there's not a lot of help in docs.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/issues/2535
Looks like caused by symfony/doctrine bridge package. Try upgrade to latest 5.4 version.